# ODBC or SQL DataSource?

Tags: sql, odbc

I want to connect my VB project to Whatever server is on the same computer.
I want to then interrogate it for the database names. `SELECT name FROM sys.databases`
Drop those database names in a drop down. Then change the connection based on the drop down selection. Is this possible?

Should I use ODBC or the SQL DataSource?

Comment: is whatever server is on the computer a sql server

Answer (score 0):

Well from what I quickly searched you would use SQL DataSource to connect to an ODBC Database.  No matter, you should always be able to give your users the control to select a database table name and then return them all the data you want from that table. This can be done with either a nice switch statement as to not trust what the user submits in the form or well actually yeah you should use a switch statement because NEVER TRUST USER INPUT.  You could get a little fancy and create a dynamic switch statement generated from a query to the DB of what tables appear in the DB and then add whatever code you need to get the return.

Hope that is a point in the correct direction for you.

**EDIT**
switch out table names for Database names, same concept though.